# Using Instance Variables vs Function Arguments in Recursion

Tags: performance, recursion, binary-search-tree

Is there any difference, efficiency-wise, in using instance variables vs passing arguments by function calls during recursion? For example, I was recently doing a problem on [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-bst-to-greater-tree/#/description) which asked to:

> Given a Binary Search Tree (BST), convert it to a Greater Tree such that every key of the original BST is changed to the original key plus sum of all keys greater than the original key in BST.

My solution and the most popular one by far is as follows: **46 ms according to Leetcode**

```
class Solution {
public:
    int sum = 0;

    TreeNode* convertBST(TreeNode* root) {
        if (root == NULL) return 0;
        convertBST(root->right);
        sum += root->val;
        root->val = sum;
        convertBST(root->left);
        return root;
    }
};
```

But why couldn't we also use the following solution, or does it matter? **59 ms runtime according to Leetcode**

```
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* convertBST(TreeNode* root, int* sum) {
        if (root == NULL) return NULL;
        convertBST(root->right, sum);
        *sum += root->val;
        root->val = *sum;
        convertBST(root->left, sum);
        return root;
    }

    TreeNode* convertBST(TreeNode* root) {
        int sum = 0;
        return convertBST(root, & sum);
    }
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Did it give you identical results in testing?  Was the performance (speed) comparable?  Where is the actual point of difference you want to ask about?  Provide data, please.

Comment: @Prune, I have updated the post to give some more data. The results were the same but the runtime changed marginally.

Comment: The stack frame needs to include an extra pointer per call in the second solution, which I'd expect to make it fractionally slower unless a compiler can optimize it away.  Also, the first version using a global value instead of stack frame pointer might translate to simpler assembly or bytecode.